# Scrollble Android ActionBar like WhatsApp and Google Playstore

Tags: android

[image: What's app]Want to achieve actionbar styling as it is currently in whatsapp and google play store application. 
An image is first overlay behind the action  bar, and as the user scrolls up, the image gradually animate to the actionbar. Perfect example is found when a user views an app on google play store android application.

Do not want to use but want to implement the design within the application.
Have read thread like [http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/05/24/pushing-the-actionbar-to-the-next-level/](http://Pushing%20the%20ActionBar%20to%20the%20Next%20Level) and  [this library](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView/tree/master/samples/src/main/java/com/github/ksoichiro/android/observablescrollview/samples) but have not been able to figure out a way to implement this fully.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I'm achieving this in my apps:

- Use a `ListView` from `ObservableScrollView`(
  https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView).
- In the `Toolbar` add a custom view with a public method inside that
  sets margins or paddings to what's inside, to the effect of
  collapsing or expanding the toolbar which is set to `wrap_content`.
- Set a header to the `ListView` to match the height of the fully expanded toolbar.
- Use the callbacks from `ObservableScrollView` to tell your custom
  view to collapse or expand.

Hope this helps.